# Chart Animation no longer works in 2016 VBA

Tags: excel, vba

this code worked perfectly in Excel 2013 but does not show the real time animation but shows only the final sketch after the code run is done completely.
Please address it.

```
Public Sub Plot_Line() ' {

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = Worksheets("Line")
Dim firstRow    As Integer
Dim lastRow     As Integer
Dim firstColumn As Integer
Dim lastColumn  As Integer

firstRow = 2
lastRow = firstRow + 302 - 1

firstColumn = 1
Dim rows As Integer
rows = lastRow - firstRow + 1
Dim columns As Integer
columns = lastColumn - firstColumn + 1


Dim dataRange As Range
Set dataRange = Range(Cells(firstRow, firstColumn + 1), Cells(lastRow, firstColumn + 2))

Set ch1 = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1")
ch1.Activate

ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
Set ch = ActiveChart
DoEvents

For t = 3 To 302

With Range("C3:C" & t)
    .Formula = "=SIN(2*A3)"
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))
    DoEvents

 End With
Next t

End Sub
```

'

Comment: any line show an error?

Comment: Your sub seems to mostly consist of code which is completely unrelated to the animation. You have all sorts of assignments which do nothing. For example -- what is the point of `columns = lastColumn - firstColumn + 1`? Why not clean it up to get a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a decent animation in Excel 2016 (which seems harder than in earlier versions because of some undocumented changes in their rendering engine) it helps to first create the chart manually. Something like this:

[image]

Make sure that the min and max in both axes are set manually rather than set to auto. If you now delete the numbers but keep the chart, an empty coordinate system will display.

As far as code goes, rather than using `Application.Wait`, kill two birds with one stone and make your own delay function which has a `DoEvents` thrown in:

```
Option Explicit 'Your code could use this!

Sub Pause(t As Double)
    Dim start As Double
    start = Timer
    Do While Timer < start + t
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

Then the animation sub is simply like this:

```
Public Sub Plot_Line()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim x As Double
    Dim y As Double

    Range("A2:B316").ClearContents
    For i = 2 To 316
        x = 0.02 * (i - 1)
        y = Sin(x) 'you could insert a formula if you prefer
        Range("A" & i).Value = x
        Range("B" & i).Value = y
        Pause 0.02
    Next i
End Sub
```

Note that the animation code doesn't directly interact with the chart. It simply controls the range that supplies the chart data. My guess is that the line

```
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
```

is the main culprit in your code. No sure why, but trying to modify the chart object itself in an animation doesn't seem to work in Excel 2016.

Comment: Your `Pause`-function will enter a *busy wait*-loop that will consume 100% CPU (at least of one core).

Comment: @FunThomas The point is that this is not a bad idea in the context of the animation. The pause is a fraction of a second and the loop isn't doing nothing -- it is causing the chart to update. For longer pauses, it would be a bad idea.

Comment: Right, but OP posted code that loops 300 times, each time waiting for 5s...

Comment: @FunThomas I see. Good point. How is an update every 5 seconds even an animation? At a glance I had misread that as 0.05 seconds. I have a lot of Excel animations, and I can usually get a decent frame-rate of 20 to 50 updates per second (depending in part on ow much of a change there is).